# Services in Laravel as a Singleton?

Tags: php, laravel-8

In my Laravel app, I use a lot of Services almost as a mini internal API which is reusable by any class. When using these services, I usually utilize dependency injection to bring the needed services into a given class.

Would it be better practice to register these services as Singletons? Would that save on resources if it is not necessary to re-instantiate them all the time?

Thanks!

Comment: If I am not totally mistaken, that's what your service providers are for. They take care of that for you.

Comment: I am not using a service in the sense of a service provider. The services I am talking about are basically custom classes which I have to call from controllers in order to use them. I was thinking that it might be more efficient to have them in the IOC container.